# Holding more than one value for a key in nested dictionary

Tags: python, key

```
mydict = {'Papa': {12:{45: {'AG'}}}}
mydict.append{'Papa':{21:{54:{'GA'}}}}
print(mydict)
{'Papa': {12:{45: {'AG'}}}, {21:{54:{'GA'}}}}
```

How can I append a value into my dictionary so that one key can hold more than one value? In this case, I want the 'Papa' key to hold both nested dictionaries as values. And is there a way to do this without using update function or e? I don't know how to use them. I just wanna do it manually.

Comment: You can't, but the value can be a list, set, ... which holds multiple values.

Comment: Ok, deleted my answer, as i think that you didn't make your problem statement clear. I think your question has a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list.

With `list()` or `[]` you declare a list. And with `mylist.append()` you add a new item to the list.

```
mydict = {'Papa': [{12:{45: {'AG'}}}]} # [] are the list
mydict['Papa'].append({21:{54:{'GA'}}}) # Append a new value to the list 'Papa'
print(mydict)
{'Papa': [{12: {45: {'AG'}}}, {21: {54: {'GA'}}}]}
```

Comment: Yeah.. this was what I was thinking of too.. but would this not be too redudant? I feel like this type of code is not very efficient.

Comment: I am not an expert but I don't seem this like a bad idea.